# Add missing index (dtype = string) to value_counts() of df in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I can't seem to find this anywhere else, and I could be wording the question incorrectly, but I am getting the value counts for the 'Type' column in adf grouped by account ID and getting results like so:

```
print(df_activities.groupby(['Account ID'])['Type'].value_counts().sort_index())

Account ID       Type        
0011N000017WOso  Call              5
                 Email           119
                 Null              2
                 Outreach         65
                 Unclassified      1
                                ... 
001o0000017a8o5  Email            46
                 LinkedIn         11
                 Null              2
                 Others            6
                 Outreach          8
```

What I would like is to only extract Call, Email, LinkedIn, and Meeting from the value counts, but if an ID is missing one of these values entirely, I need it to show that there are 0 present. For example, this would be the ideal output of the above:

```
Account ID       Type        
0011N000017WOso  Call              5
                 Email           119
                 LinkedIn          0
                 Meeting           0
                                ... 
001o0000017a8o5  Email            46
                 Call              0
                 LinkedIn         11
                 Meeting           0
```

I want to map these to separate columns afterwards, with something like this:

```
df_acc['Email Activity'] = df_acc['Account ID'].map(df_contacts.groupby(['Account ID'])['Type']='Email'.sum())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `value_counts`, use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['Account ID'], df['Type']).stack()
```

For only specific types:

```
types = ['Call', 'Email', 'LinkedIn', 'Meeting']
out = (pd.crosstab(df['Account ID'], df['Type'])
         .reindex(columns=types, fill_value=0).stack()
      )
```

Output:

```
Account ID       Type    
0011N000017WOso  Call          5
                 Email       119
                 LinkedIn      0
                 Meeting       0
001o0000017a8o5  Call          0
                 Email        46
                 LinkedIn     11
                 Meeting       0
dtype: int64
```

Variant that might be a bit more efficient if there are many non-target categories:

```
types = ['Call', 'Email', 'LinkedIn', 'Meeting']
m = df['Type'].isin(types)
out = (pd.crosstab(df.loc[m, 'Account ID'], df.loc[m, 'Type'])
         .reindex(columns=types, fill_value=0).stack()
      )
```

Comment: This is great and gives me exactly what I need, but how can I then map these to new columns for each account ID? I would like a column that contains the call count, email count, linkedin count, and meeting count for each ID, but not sure how to extract the data

Comment: @Luke this looks like this should be a different question with enough details and reproducible inputs. Looks like a `merge` to me.

Comment: Found that removing .stack and then merging with `df_acc = df_acc.merge(out, left_on='Account ID', right_index=True)` worked!

Answer (score 2):

To address the first point, you can use [categorical data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) :

```
items = ["Call", "Email", "LinkedIn", "Meeting"]
types = pd.CategoricalDtype(items, ordered=True)

vc = (df_activities.astype({"Type": types})
          .groupby(["Account ID"])["Type"]
          .value_counts(sort=False)
     )
```

Output of `vc` :

```
Account ID       Type    
0011N000017WOso  Call          5
                 Email       119
                 LinkedIn      0
                 Meeting       0
001o0000017a8o5  Call          0
                 Email        46
                 LinkedIn     11
                 Meeting       0
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Used input :

```
op = """
    Account ID       Type        
    0011N000017WOso  Call              5
                     Email           119
                     Null              2
                     Outreach         65
                     Unclassified      1
    001o0000017a8o5  Email            46
                     LinkedIn         11
                     Null              2
                     Others            6
                     Outreach          8
"""

from io import StringIO

df_activities = (pd.read_fwf(StringIO(op)).ffill()
                 .pipe(lambda x: x.loc[x.index.repeat(x["Unnamed: 2"])]))
```

Comment: I like the categorical, but there's a more straightforward method IMO :p

Comment: Many roads lead to Rome :p and TBH, your `ct` is dope but maybe you need to filter the `Type` *s*.

Comment: that's right :)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC You just need to add a filter before doing the group by and count to get your desired output. See example below using dummy data:

```
# Dummy init
choices = ['Linked', "Email", "Random", "Others" ,"Call", "Meeting"]
n =100
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type':np.random.choice(choices, size=n), 'Account ID': ['abc']*n, })

# declare your list of required types here
required_types = ['Linked', "Email","Call", "Meeting"]
df_sub = df[df['Type'].isin(required_types)] # temp dataframe
print(df_sub.groupby(['Account ID'])['Type'].value_counts().sort_index())
```

Print:

```
Account ID  Type   
abc         Call       18
            Email      16
            Linked     16
            Meeting    17
Name: Type, dtype: int64
```

Comment: If really OP only needs one subtype, this is indeed the preferred approach ;)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked (credit to @mozway for the basis of this):

```
types = ['Call', 'Email', 'LinkedIn Task', 'Meeting']
m = df_activities['Type'].isin(types)
out = (pd.crosstab(df_activities.loc[m, 'Account ID'], df_activities.loc[m, 'Type'])
       .reindex(columns=types, fill_value=0)
       )
df_acc = df_acc.merge(out, left_on='Account ID', right_index=True)
```